# Windows Phone app header different when debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1, blend

I am trying to make my first windows phone app by using Blend and Visual Studio 2013. My header text that I added for the hub is different when I run the app in the emulator.

The header should be 'multi timer'but instead when I run the app it is 'application name'. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if the application name is declared on the page or in the App.xaml file. Look for this line and change the

```html
<x:String x:Key="AppName">My Application</x:String>
```